# What is a totally ordered sort of sets of a partial order called?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-algorithms, terminology

Given a DAG, which can represent a partial order and has at least one topological sort.

For example the graph

```
  >B
 /  \
A    >D
 \  /
  >C
```

has two topological sorts "ABCD" and "ACBD".

My question is the following:
*Is there a name for the following total order sort of sets:*

`S:  ( {A} , {B,C} , {D} )`

The inductive definition is similar to constructing a topological sort:

1. Put the all the graph minima (nodes with no input edges) in set #i `S: ( {A} )`
2. Remove the graph minima from the graph.  `G:= G \ {A}`
3. repeat step 1. with `i := i+1` as long as the graph is non-empty

I find this in several computer science domains. For example method selection in CLOS (Common Lisp), a parallel scheduler of a DAG where nodes are tasks and edges dependencies, the list of all enabled sets in dataflow or petri-net model executions, etc.  I haven't found a single nomenclature or even a reference for it though.  It sounds simple and pervasive enough to merit one.

Comment: I would just call it a greedy partition into antichains.

Comment: alternately, you could call it a layered decomposition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the context of geometric dominance orders, the standard term is "layers of maxima" (in your case, minima). Obviously, the same term can be used for any partial order.

http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/11785293_34

http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00453-004-1082-5

Comment: Which is also called a 'skyline' apparently, according to one of those papers.  Thank you!